# Does Windows Server 2019 support SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint

We are planning to upgrade our Windows Server from 2012 R2 to Windows Server 2019. We have SharePoint 2016 installed in the Server. Can anybody please advise if Windows Server 2019 support SharePoint 2016. If Yes please let me know the impact

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does, checkout the documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/hardware-and-software-requirements